# Access 2012 importing a 500MB text file results in an out of disk space error

Tags: vba, t-sql, import

I have a 500MB txt file. It is not a CSV file (it does not have any delimitiers other than spaces), so I can't import it using tSQL. Currently I am trying with the help of Access's import specifications. I figured out how to call it in code and polished the code so I can import a small file (test file was 200kb large). But now i have the exact file i have to import and its 500MB in size. When i run my code it gets to around 50%, and then throws an "Your computer is out of disk space. You won't be able to undo this paste append. Do you want to continue anyway?" error.

I am inserting into a linked SQL table.

What can I do to get rid of this error and what exactly is causing it (I have plenty of disk space and memory capacity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to solve it using tsql. The problem was the columns in the file were not separated with any separators. So I create an import specification in access (the one where you pick where you want each column to be). Then i just used the specification as the reference for writing a tsql procedure, which uses bulk insert and then gets each "column" out of the txt file using SUBSTRING (access specification gives you the range to use in substring).

Now works without any problems. It takes about 20 min to import the 500MB file. But i have a job at night that runs it so thats not a problem.

Thank you all for your help. This question is now closed. Any questions about my solution, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can bulk insert space delimited files in T-SQL like so:

```
BULK INSERT yourTable
   FROM 'C:/<filepath>/yourTextFile.txt'
   WITH 
      (
         --Space delimited
         FIELDTERMINATOR =' ',

         --New rows starts at new line
         ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'

         --Use this if you have a header row with your column names. 
         --,FIRSTROW = 2
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have disk space space?  It does not just make up those messages.

Is the disk space actually allocated to data data and log files?

Comment: There is atelast 300GB of free diskspace